# Rails: some javascript not working in production ONLY on a Windows computer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on a rails web app that I'm hosting on a DigitalOcean server.

It runs on ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.0.

When I access the website on Chrome or Firefox on my Linux machine, it works perfectly fine. Same on an Android device.
But when I access it on a Windows computer, some JavaScript plugins and gems are not working.

For example, I'm using [Trumbowyg](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg) as a wysiwyg editor, [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and [font awesome](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) and none of them are working, while some other JavaScript plugins seem to work, like bootstrap.

I checked on the Chrome console and all the code seem to be included in the `application.js` file in both Linux and Windows. On Windows, the console doesn't recognize my plugins, where on linux it does. In both systems, jQuery is working properly.

I don't understand how it can work on Android and Linux but not on Windows.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: (1). check the version of the browser in windows, if it's to old try to update it with the latest, (2) check browser add on, some add on disable javascript. (3) try different browser in windows firefox, chrome..

Comment: @widjajayd I tried on the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and even Edge on Windows, with no add-ons and JavaScript enabled. I tried that on 3 different Windows devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by creating a new manifest file and importing all my JavaScript modules and coffee files in it.

I included it in my layout and added it to the `assets.rb` file for precompilation.